# Apache CXF Https issue

Tags: cxf, jbossfuse

I have generated self signed certificate using keytool command. and successfully configured https at jboss fuse level and port assigned to it is 8443. `https://localhost:8443/hawtio/login` works perfectly fine. In apache cxf i am facing issue. following configuration is done in blueprint xml file.

```
<cxf:rsServer address="http://0.0.0.0:9192/"
        id="serviceOrderEndpoint" serviceClass="pk.com.telenor.so.controller.ServiceOrder"/>

  <cxfcore:bus/>

  <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
      <httpj:engine port="8443">
        <httpj:tlsServerParameters secureSocketProtocol="TLSv1">
          <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
            <sec:keyStore resource="certs/jbossfuse-dev.jks" password="password" type="JKS"/>
          </sec:keyManagers>
          <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore resource="certs/jbossfuse-dev.jks" password="password" type="JKS"/>
          </sec:trustManagers>
          <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_3DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:exclude>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:exclude>
            <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
          </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
          <sec:clientAuthentication want="true" required="false"/>
        </httpj:tlsServerParameters>
      </httpj:engine>
    </httpj:engine-factory>
```

I want to run it on https://localhost:9192/
In pom.xml file i have placed the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the issue that i am facing

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding not found by org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-wsdl
```

Comment: why are you mixing different CXF versions? why not using a more recent version? latest release is 3.2.0

Comment: Yes make sure to use the same version of CXF for all your CXF dependencies. Also if you are using JBoss Fuse, you should use the CXF version that comes out of the box with JBoss Fuse.

Comment: @DennisKieselhorst, i have upgraded cxf version to 3.2.0. Now 
 this is the issue: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to load class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector from recipe MapRecipe[name='#recipe-2734']

Answer (score 0):

When you said "configured https at jboss fuse level " I believe you mean you configured in the $JBOSS_FUSE/etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg.

Then as your cxf rs endpoint get deployed into the JBoss FUSE container, the best practice is that this endpoint use the servlet transport managed by this container(the HTTP OSGi service implmented by OPS4J PAXWEB with jetty), so your configuration address for the cxf:rsServer should be relative address like address="/myendpoint", then you can access it from
 https://localhost:8443/cxf/myendpoint.
Also, as the https already configured at JBoss FUSE level, you don't need      
`<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
...
</httpj:engine-factory>`
stuff.

Freeman

Comment: Thank you for response. As i mentioned in my question i want to access it on https://localhost:9192/ url